# UICollectionView Horizontal align scroll first cell center alignment not exactly placing center position very first time using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My scenario, I am trying to Implement `UICollectionView` horizontal `scrollview` first and last cell center alignment based on selection. Here, Very first time `CollectionViewCell` first cell not showing exact center position. If I `didselect` once everything working fine.
I need to fix very first time app open first cell not showing exact center position.

NOTE: I didn’t added header and footer also I am done my designing using storyboard.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        let cellWidth = text.size(withAttributes:[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)]).width + 10.0
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let inset: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width * 0.5 - 52 * 0.5
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: inset, bottom: 0, right: inset)
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use 52 directly since the width of each cell is dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `52` directly since as the `cell width`, since the `width` of each `cell` is `dynamic`.

You need to calculate the `leftInsets` and `rightInsets` of the `collectionView` based on the `actual width` of `first` and `last` `cell`.

You can calculate the `width` of `first` and `last` `cell` the same way you did in `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt)` method using the `first` and `last` `element` of `items array`, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    //Calculate width of first cell
    var firstCellWidth: CGFloat = 52.0
    if let textAtFirstIndex = self.items.first {
        firstCellWidth = textAtFirstIndex.size(withAttributes:[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)]).width + 10.0
    }

    //Calculate width of last cell
    var lastCellWidth: CGFloat = 52.0
    if let textAtLastIndex = self.items.last {
        lastCellWidth = textAtLastIndex.size(withAttributes:[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)]).width + 10.0
    }

    //Calculate leftInset and rightInset
    let leftInset: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.width * 0.5) - (firstCellWidth * 0.5)
    let rightInset: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.width * 0.5) - (lastCellWidth * 0.5)

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftInset, bottom: 0, right: rightInset)
}
```

**Example:**

[image]

Let me know in case you still face any issues.

Comment: Awesome. Working charm.Thank you @PGDev